# Create global NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

I have a class:

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    func fetchProducts() {
         let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
         backgroundQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
         for n in items {
             backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
                self.someFunc(n)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

If i understand, for each instance i create max 5 threads. But i want to create global `NSOperationQueue()`

I created global struct:

```
struct GVariables {
    static let globalBackgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
}
```

The problem: How to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` and other settings ?

Because if i modify method like this:

```
func fetchProducts() {
   GVariables.globalBackgroundQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
}
```

It will be the same ? or not ?

Comment: Why don't you add this in a extension

Comment: but if i want to use this for other classes, etc. ?

Comment: Try in a Model class??

Comment: I see you are using Core Data. Remember, managed objects are only safe to access inside their context's queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, I would do something more like this:

```
struct GlobalQueue {
    static let globalBackgroundQueue = GlobalQueue()
    let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    private init () {
         backgroundQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
         //... more settings

    }
}
```

This is a *singleton* that holds an instance of itself. You can initialize whatever values you want in your initializer. Note the private keyword which insures that you can't make more than one instance of this class.

Obligatory Disclaimer: beware singletons...